# Can't enable ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` which I am placing in a `SourceGrid3` control, but for some reason I can't set the `Enabled` attribute to `true`.

Here is my code.

```
ComboBox cboMyComboBox = new ComboBox(); 
cboMyComboBox.Enabled = true;
cboMyComboBox.BeginUpdate(); 
cboMyComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Accept", "Reject" });
cboMyComboBox.EndUpdate();
cboMyComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
SourceGrid3.Cells.Real.CellControl thisControl = new SourceGrid3.Cells.Real.CellControl(cboMyComboBox);

myGrid[row, column] = thisControl;
```

(`myGrid` is the `SourceGrid3` grid)

For some reason when the last line gets executed, the `Enabled` value gets turned to `false` and subsequent attempts to change it (like setting it back to `true`) don't have any effect.

Even if I try and change the value to `true` in the Visual Studio debugger, it won't allow it and simply changes it back to `false`.  I have looked for a `ReadOnly` attribute for this field but there doesn't seem to be one (unless I'm missing something) besides I can change other attributes (like `RightToLeft` from `No` to `Yes`)

Is there anything else I can check that might cause this control to be forced to `false` ?

Comment: Isn't the default 'true' as well ? Is it even disabled if you don't set the property ?

Comment: @FeDe Yeah even if I don't explicitly set it to `true`, it does default to `true`, but then changes to `false` when I add it to the grid...

Comment: Have you tried setting the Enabled property on the grid ? mybe its forced by parent control ..

Comment: @FeDe - Yes of course that's it alright... If you feel like posting that as an answer, then I'll accept it... :)

Comment: that would be nice. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Problem:**

If a general Property which exists in all `UI-Elements` is set for a `Control` it will pass its value down to all child elements.

Speaking generally this will overwrite the Value of this property for **all** child controls.

**The Solution:**

> Set the `Enabled`-Property for your `Grid` to `true` and leave it
>   unassigned in your `ComboBox` **or** just remove the `Enabled=false` in your grids definition.